# How can I stop chocolate chips sinking to the bottom when I make cakes?

Tags: baking, cake

I love making and eating chocolate chip cakes - both large cakes and cupcakes, but almost always when I make them, the chocolate chips sink to the bottom (or, occasionally, rise to the top).

Is there anything I can do to try and stop this happening? If so, what?

Comment: I have this problem as well when I put m&m's in a cake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coat the chocolate chips in flour (whichever type of flour goes into your cake).  Put a few ounces or two of flour and the chocolate chips into a zip-top bag, close tightly and shake.  The coated chips will then adhere and tend to "float" in the batter.  Subtract the amount flour used to coat the chips from the flour otherwise used in the recipe.

You could do this with cocoa powder instead of flour.

Comment: Being lazy on the whole subtraction thing, when I've done this (for blueberry muffins, never tried it for chocolate chips), I measure out the flour, then just scoop some out of the stuff I've already measured.

Answer (score 2):

These tips should help:

1. Dust the chocolate chips with flour or cocoa powder as suggested by @KatieK
2. Use mini chocolate chips or chop the bigger chocolate chips into smaller bits. The weight of the cake should be enough to hold the weight of the chocolate chips and bigger chocolate chips will more than likely sink.
3. Try sprinkling the chocolate chips over the cake instead of folding them in
4. Add a lesser amount of chocolate chips than what the recipe calls for