# Shaved chocolate in cake batter?

Tags: baking

If I shaved a white chocolate bar and put the shavings in a cake batter, would they melt or harden?

Comment: Is the cake batter hot or cold?

Comment: I think what we need to know is... will this batter then go in the oven? Based on your calling it "batter", I'm guessing the answer is "yes".

Comment: It will be just a cold cupcake batter that will be put into the oven. I just need to know if the shavings will melt or if they will harden into little pieces inside the cupcake.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience it's likely that chocolate shavings are too small to keep any integrity during baking. They will likely melt into the batter as it bakes. If the batter is warm it may already melt then.

Larger pieces like chocolate chips are more likely to stay together enough to re-solidify into noticeable pieces when eaten.

Comment: I have tried this years ago with chocolate chips (regular dark ones), and they sank to the bottom -- or perhaps they floated to the top? --  At any rate they all headed in one direction, creating a "chocolate layer", and did not remain homogeneously distributed throughout the cake.

Comment: @LorelC.
Looks like there are answers to that too. [How to stop chocolate chips sinking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15369/how-can-i-stop-chocolate-chips-sinking-to-the-bottom-when-i-make-cakes)

Answer (score 1):

Chocolate (white or not) cannot "harden" much from baking, unless it is essentially burned. Things that "harden" when cooked/baked do so by either drying (chocolate *is already dry*) or by proteins/starches/sugars changing (chocolate has not much protein or starch, and at the temperatures where sugars change chemically, chocolate is likely to burn). The more unfortunate possibilities would be fats polymerizing (you don't want that happening to your chocolate either) or pyrolizing (hardening because ash is hard).

However, chocolate that has been molten and resolified will usually be more matte and softer than before it (since it is no longer properly tempered).

Comment: I get the feeling the questioner is wondering whether the white chocolate shavings will dissolve into the batter and be imperceptible in the finished cake, or will they melt, but then *re*-harden and remain as interesting textural features of the finished cake

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to ask. I want to make a chocolate cupcake with white chocolate peppermint shavings. I want that flavor in the cupcakes and not have it interfere with the texture of the cupcake itself. I would use peppermint extract, but was asked not to use it.